# Bringing an absolute positioned sub-menu forward?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I've got an id `#navigation` with `position: relative;` and inside of it a class `.submenu` with `position:absolute;`. The sub-menu contains texts (`<a>` tag links more specifically), which have lost their `cursor: pointer;` property and ability to be selected on the account of them now being behind other elements on the page.

I'm not sure what I can do, short of declaring `#navigation` and all it's children at the bottom of the page in order to bring `.submenu` "to the front".

I've already tried setting `z-index: 1`; on `.submenu`, and that didn't work.

Any more suggestions/answers would be greatly appreciated ;)!

Comment: one one sentence or less, describe what your problem is, and how you need help to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace #navigation .submenu with this:

```
#navigation .submenu {
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 445px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Tested and working. Add the z-index and create a background color so that the other elements arent bleeding through—Nick B

Answer (score 1):

I added this code using inline-styling to the div of class `submenu`

```
style="z-index: 999"
```

and it worked

[image]
[image]